# Opencv recorded video is too slow and camera update is very slow

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, video, computer-vision

Please help me understand why video recorded using Opencv is so slow. It does not reflect quick movements.
For example, if I move the camera then the movement is too slow in the video. Also, though I showed a picture in front of the camera for about 2 seconds, I did not see the picture in the recording.

Can someone explain me please what is going on here.
This is my simple code:

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output2.avi',fourcc, 30.0, (640,480))

while (True):

    camera.capture(stream, use_video_port=True, format='jpeg') 
    stream.seek(0)
    imageData = np.fromstring(stream.getvalue(), dtype=np.uint8)
    npImage = cv2.imdecode(imageData, 1) 
    out.write(npImage)
    stream.close()
```

Comment: not sure what it does, but do you really want/have to camera.capture(stream, use_video_port=True, format='jpeg') 
    stream.seek(0) and stream.close() in every iteration of the loop?

Comment: Is camera.capture() the function that gets frames from the camera? Try to capture frames in a separate thread and put it in a queue to be accessed whenever you need. This might help you I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the hint
can you please explain more your idea?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will fix your problem. You can define a separate function that acquires frames from the camera and puts it in a queue. You can run this function in a separate thread. Refer to this [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) for documentation on threading. This speeds up the process of getting frames from the camera because the cap.read() function is a blocking function (if you are using cap=cv2.VideoCapture()).

The code would be something like this.

```
def getf(queue):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)    
    while(processing):
        fr = {}
        ret, a = cap.read()
        if ret:
            fr["imagecaptured"]=a
            queue.put(fr)
        else:
            #whatever you want to do when a frame is unable to be read from cam
    cap.release()

stream = threading.Thread(target=getf, args=queue)
```

Note that 'processing' in the above code example is a global variable. Now, you can define a function to set processing to be true, and start the thread with 'stream.start()' command or put this directly in the program.

Once the thread is started, frames are continuously put in queue for you to read when you want. With the below code, you have the frame.

```
if not queue.empty():
    capturedframe = queue.get()
    frame = capturedframe["imagecaptured"]
```

I used this method to stream from camera and at same time do something else. Referred from a [link](https://www.kurokesu.com/main/2016/08/01/opencv-usb-camera-widget-in-pyqt/) on making a webcam widget with pyqt. Note that the above code snippets are for an example and are not read to be run. Apart from definitions, I suggest you also include a condition to keep check on queue size. You can now modify this to use for your application and see if it does the job. You can also refer to this [link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/12/21/increasing-webcam-fps-with-python-and-opencv/) for a similar example.

Answer (score 0):

Running multiple threads in python is certainly a good suggestion, however you will find that the majority of realtime video programs are written in compiled languages like C++, possibly with some assembler/sse chops thrown in..... and I won't even bother addressing GPU acceleration.
If you run multiple threads in python, you may convert your problem to a different form of certain death, in that the queue will fill faster than you can empty it and you will finally run out of memory if the video keeps streaming in.
The best approach is to use an optimized package to acquire, broadcast, and record video - for example, in my public projects on github, I have Dantalion, which is a C++ client that handles real time acquisition and certain image processing tasks such as rectification and disparity calcs -  it also pumps the images into a MQTT server, where the python DantalionClient app that takes TOO D**N LONG :-( can do things like search for checkerboards and compute intrinsics and extrinsics. I also elect to run the client on a separate machine, since the Dantalion host is a SoC (Beaglebone)
I'd strongly recommend you load up your arsenal.  Python is one of my best friends, but if I care about speed and the flow of bits and you aren't going to make me do a lot of algebra, C++ is my tool of choice.  Python is not the right tool for simply getting a large mass of raw imagery from point a to point b.
Don't get me wrong - I'm not recommending my stuff - it's way too specialized - I'm just using it as an example of why you may want to consider an alternative language/toolchain - there's a reason they exist.